# Moving a rigged jawbone

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

I weight painted the jawbone along with the lower jaw, but whenever I rotate the jawbone armature, the jaw comes out. What can I do to keep it in the mouth while moving it?
[image: Thokgo jaw 6]
https://blend-exchange.com/b/bD1K1ML6

Comment: This needs a lot more detail.  You should consider linking a file so people can see what you're talking about (and why it's happening.)

Comment: Try https://pasteall.org/blend/

Answer (score 1):

If we go to weight paint mode and select a vertex that doesn't seem to be moving right, then inspect its deforming weights on the sidebar, we can see why:

[image]

This vertex is weighted 1.0 to the jawbone-- but it's also weighted to a bunch of other bones.  Its effective influence from the jawbone is equal to 1/(.009+.214+.734+1).  So it's effectively only weighted half way to the jawbone.

If we select one of the teeth vertices instead, we'll see that those are weighted fully to the jawbone, but not to any other bones, so the teeth are influenced fully by the jawbone.

If you want these to match up, you either have to paint the teeth to match the lips, or the lips to match the teeth.  In respect to **all** bones, not just one bone.  There are a number of tools you can use to make them match (data transfer, normalize all operation with locked groups, more.)